# Restful principles - sending user's identifier in HTTP headers

Tags: rest

I'm creating restful api that is used by angular web page. I'm using token based authentication. Server side determines which user sent request based on token value, so I don't have to pass user id on URI. For example, request that returns all orders for logged (with token) user looks like this:

```
    /api/orders
```

instead of:

```
    /api/users/123/orders
```

Api is still stateless, but the same URI returns different data depending on headers. Is it consistent with Restful principles?

Comment: Yes, it is as server hasn't any state.

Comment: Though, consider what happens when you have an app that needs to get the orders from another user. I would keep the user ID in the path. If you have a good framework, you could probably intercept the request, and fill out URI segments based on the headers that are present in the request. Such as for instance userId and orderId, then map those to match /api/users/{userId}/orders/{orderId}.

Comment: one other thing to consider which I just realized, you could have two URIs
/api/users/{userid}/orders/{orderid}
/api/user/orders <- this one depends on headers

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig 
Solution with two URIs looks good. When user wants to get his own orders, then he will call /api/orders. When he wants to get other user's orders, he will call /api/users/userId/orders.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this suggested API violates the address-ability feature of REST. The address of a resource should be in a form that is visible and readable (and some other things not related to your question...). One of the nice things of nice URIs is that one can link to it easily. Headers are actually hiding the real address of the resource hence making it impossible to link to it. So bottom line I would not go for such an API.

Comment: But when you want to get your orders, is it more readable to call /api/orders or /api/users/userId/orders ? You have to pass your id although you already set your token in HTTP header.

Comment: But in your way it will be impossible to send the URI from one to another and actually refer to the same resource as it is personalized to the actual user being logged in. This is not the way REST APIs are constructed.